# Reading data into an array from a copy of a FILE used to write

Tags: c, file, argv

I have a FILE object that writes to argv[1] in my program

```
tabptr = fopen(argv[1],w+)
```

And i need to read from that same file, but how would i create a pointer to tabptr that can read from argv[1] instead of write? Or am i just over thinking this process.

```
tabptr = fopen(argv[1],w+)
//tabptr writes to argv[1]...
//time to declare file to read from the same tabptr wrote to
FILE * tabptrStr = tabptr   //how would i make tabptrStr readable?
tabptrStr = fopen(argv[1],"r") //or am i just overthinking this and this will accomplish my goal?
```

argv[1] is just what confuses me, i'm new to c coming from C++

Answer (score 1):

You read *and* write with the same `FILE*`. It's the mode given to [`fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen), which decides whether you can read and/or write to a file.

So you can either

```
fread(buf, 17, 1, tabptr);
```

or

```
fwrite(buf, 17, 1, tabptr);
```

with tabptr.

`argv[1]` usually is a parameter given to the program in `main()`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
...
}
```

and in this case names the file you should use for reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

`argc` is the number of command line arguments passed to main and `argv` is an array of pointers to those arguments (argv[0] is the program name). In your case argv[1] is the name of the file opened for read/write.

The second argument to `fopen` denotes the file opening mode, so you have already opened the file both for read and write and `tabptr` can be used for the same. Only note that opening in `w+` mode will discard the contents of the file if it already exists.